# lightning:navigation defaultFieldValues not working in lightning communiy

Tags: aura, quickaction, lightningnavigation

I have this custom aura component that redirects to `New Opportunity` standard record creation with some fields pre-populated from Account record.

cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">

    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>

    <lightning:pageReferenceUtils aura:id="pagerefUtils"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myAction}"/>

</aura:component>
```

controller.js:

```
({
  myAction: function (component, event, helper) {
    let navigate = component.find("navService");
    let pageRef = {
        type : 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes : {
            objectApiName : 'Opportunity',
            actionName : 'new'
        },
        state : { }
    };
    let defaultFieldValues = {
        Name: 'testing',
        AccountId : component.get("v.recordId")
    };
    pageRef.state.defaultFieldValues = component.find("pagerefUtils").encodeDefaultFieldValues(defaultFieldValues);
    navigate.navigate(pageRef);
  }
})
```

But for some reason is redirecting fine to standard record creation but without pre-populated field values and not retrieving any error.

Is there something I'm missing when calling `lightning:navigation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:pageReferenceUtils/documentation):

> This component is not supported in Lightning Out, **Lightning communities**, or the Salesforce mobile app.

(my emphasis)

Comment: So right now there's no away I can achieve this in lightning community with this or any other kind of implementation? Cause I need to pre-populate some values

Comment: Try using Doug Ayers' [legitimate URL hacking in LEX](https://douglascayers.com/2018/08/05/legitimate-url-hacking-in-lightning-experience/) component. We use this to good effect.